# How to bind List<> to DatagridView

Tags: c#

How to bind `List<>` to `DatagridView` in C# ?

```
List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();
```

Comment: what is list<T> type here ..

Comment: What kind of application you are targetting ? Winform, WPF, ASP.Net

Comment: The line `List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();` doesn't add any information to your question, unless you want to show us that you know how to instantiate a list in C#. Please, try to be more specific.

Answer (score 5):

Should look something like this:

```
var bs = new BindingSource();
var list = new List<YourType> { ... };
bs.DataSource = list;
grid.DataSource = bs;
```

Comment: What if you're grabbing a table from the database?

Answer (score 1):

It should work

```
 BindingList<MyList> Categories = new BindingList<MyList>();
            Categories.Add(new MyList("Hello"));

            dataGridView1.DataSource = Categories;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply bind it like this

```
List<object> itemList = new List<object>();
grid.DataSource = itemList;
grid.DataBind();
```